# How can we retry loading the image in the NetworkImage widget if an error occurred while loading it

Tags: flutter, dart

How can we let the user to be able to reload his image if an error occurred while loading the image in the NetworkImage, I showed a icon to retry in the middle of the box that contains the image, but I want to let the user be able to reload it if an error occurred and he press on the button.

Note: I know that I can make setState({}) to reload the screen again, I don't want this solution because it will leads to re-render the whole screen again, if there's any other solution.

```
FadeInImage(
              placeholder: const AssetImage('assets/images/Bird_logo.jpeg'),
              image: const NetworkImage(
                  'http://localhost:8080/resources/uploads/cover_pics/Screenshot 2023-02-13 at 9.43.41 AM.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                print(error);
                UserData.setIsCoverImageErrorLoading(true);
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: _retryImageLoad,
                  child: Text('hello'),
                );
              },
            ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can use provider or Getx packages for state management. If you don't want to use any packages, then use a combination of GestureDetector and FadeInImage widgets to achieve this. Then use this widget inside a stateless widget.

Here's an example:

```
class ReloadableImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imageUrl;

  ReloadableImage({required this.imageUrl});

  @override
  _ReloadableImageState createState() => _ReloadableImageState();
}

class _ReloadableImageState extends State<ReloadableImage> {
  bool _isLoading = true;
  bool _hasError = false;

  void _retryLoading() {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
      _hasError = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _hasError ? _retryLoading : null,
      child: _hasError
          ? Center(
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                onPressed: _retryLoading,
              ),
            )
          : FadeInImage(
              placeholder: AssetImage('assets/images/placeholder.png'),
              image: NetworkImage(widget.imageUrl),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              onError: (_, __) {
                setState(() {
                  _isLoading = false;
                  _hasError = true;
                });
              },
              onLoad: (_, __) {
                setState(() {
                  _isLoading = false;
                });
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to handle this case:

```
class BuildNetworkImage extends StatefulWidget {
  const BuildNetworkImage({
    Key? key,
    required this.imageURL,
    this.scale,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String imageURL;
  final double? scale;

  @override
  State<BuildNetworkImage> createState() => _BuildNetworkImageState();
}

class _BuildNetworkImageState extends State<BuildNetworkImage> {
  Key _key = UniqueKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Image.network(
      widget.imageURL,
      key: ValueKey(_key),
      scale: widget.scale ?? 1.0,
      loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) => loadingProgress == null
          ? child
          : Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 2.5,
                color: Colors.green,
                value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                    ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                    : null,
              ),
            ),
      errorBuilder: (context, exception, stackTrace) => IconButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() => _key = UniqueKey()),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```